# Aurora Mysql takes lot of time to write csv records

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, jooq

I am trying to write my csv file records into Aurora Mysql RDS.
I didn't made any settings/performance tuning.

```
it is taking 7 minutes to write 500 lines/records
```

Is it normal or do I need to change any settings.
I am using jooq.

```
Loader<?> loader = create.loadInto(Tables.DUMMY_PROCESS_LISTING)
        .onErrorIgnore()
        .loadCSV(new File("/tmp/" + fileName))
        .fields(Tables.DUMMY_PROCESS_LISTING.COL1,
                Tables.DUMMY_PROCESS_LISTING.COL2,
                Tables.DUMMY_PROCESS_LISTING.COL3)
        .execute();​
```

Current Max thread connection is 40 - default one. 
CPU usage is around 7%

Comment: Where is this code actually running, relative to the location of the Aurora server?  What do you see if you repeatedly run the query `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` on a different connection while the data is loading?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment on your Amazon setup and on your concrete databasese, but from the jOOQ side, there are some ways to tune the `Loader` API.

#### Default loader commit / batch / bulk values:

The default commit / batch / bulk flags on jOOQ's `LoaderOptionsStep` are:

- [`commitNone()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/LoaderOptionsStep.html#commitNone--)
- [`batchNone()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/LoaderOptionsStep.html#batchNone--)
- [`bulkNone()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/LoaderOptionsStep.html#bulkNone--)

This is usually not the fastest way to insert data, especially if there is a significant amount of latency between the client and the server. Here's an explanation for each:

#### Commit sizes

The commit size specifies how many batches should be executed in one transaction. In many databases, having a commit size that is too small will negatively affect performance as there is too much work on the UNDO/REDO log by the process that imports the data. Conversely, having a commit size that is too large will also negatively affect performance, as there might be substantial work on the UNDO log on *other* transactions (especially in MVCC transaction models).

In your case, this shouldn't be a problem, as you're only inserting 500 rows.

#### Batch sizes

In jOOQ-speak, a "batch" is the same thing as a JDBC batch, so the batch size is the number of individual insert statements that are sent to the server in a single batch statement.

Batching optimises latency because it allows for sending several statements in a single go to a server.

The default is not to batch any statements. Here, you can definitely gain quite a bit of throughput.

#### Bulk sizes

In jOOQ-speak, a "bulk" corresponds to a "bulk of rows" that are inserted / modified by a single statement. For instance, if you specify a bulk size of 5, then 5 rows will be inserted with a single statement, e.g.:

```sql
INSERT INTO t (a, b, c)
VALUES (1, 2, 3),
       (2, 3, 4),
       (3, 4, 5),
       (4, 5, 6),
       (5, 6, 7);
```

If the above syntax is not supported, jOOQ will emulate it as follows:

```sql
-- Depending on the database, FROM DUAL or something similar is added, too.
INSERT INTO t (a, b, c)
SELECT 1, 2, 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 3, 4 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 4, 5 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 5, 6 UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 6, 7;
```

A bulk insert operation optimises performance inside of the database, as the database can optimise for the insertion of several rows, e.g. allocating disk space.

As a side-effect, of course, this also optimises latency, because a single statement will now transfer 5 rows over the wire from the client to the server.

This is also something that could benefit you.

#### Other reasons

Again, these are means to tune jOOQ's `Loader` API. There may be other ways to tune your database, which are not related to jOOQ.